# Tag creation in Gitlab Repository using Gitlab api

Tags: git, api, gitlab, devops, gitlab-api

i have 4 repositories in GitLab named Repo1, Repo2, Repo3 and Repo4

now how can i create tag v1.0 for all the Repo's master branch using GitLab api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [`POST /projects/:id/repository/tags`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html#create-a-new-tag) create new tag API, the call would be:

```sh
curl -X POST "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags?tag_name=v1.0&ref=master&release_description='a short description'&private_token=${GITLAB_TOKEN}"
```

Replace `CI_PROJECT_ID` with [your GitLab project id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39572304/6309).

As shown in [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 119136](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/119136), that works for short one-line tag description only.

This creates a lightweight tag.
An annotated tag would need a `&message='...'` parameter.

You can see an [alternative call here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38272865/6309).

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225768/discussion-between-vonc-and-kiran), the OP confirms:

```sh
curl -X POST "http://198.x.y.z/api/v4/projects/2345/repository/tags?tag_name=v1.0&ref=master&release_description='first%20tag'&private_token=**************"
```

(replacing any space with `%20` in the release description) works.

> it works, but showing `{"tag_name":"v1.5","description":"'first tag'"},"protected":false}`
> Can I make this protected as true?

That would require another [API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_tags.html#protect-repository-tags).
Example:

```sh
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/protected_tags?name=*-stable&create_access_level=30"
```

With:

`create_access_level`: Access levels allowed to create (defaults: `40`, maintainer access level)

Comment: @kiran The GitLab project ID. I have edited the answer to add a link explaining how to find your GitLab project ID.

Comment: a  full-fledged tag is nothing but annoted tag which includes tag message, while light weight tag doesnot include tag message and can be pull or push

Comment: @kiran The command I mention in the answer is for lightweight tag: I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: i tried this but not working, can you write an example commad

Comment: @kiran Can you check the alternative call I mention in the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38272865/6309). Also, is there any error message. Are you using the correct project ID?

Comment: Yes there is an error message "400 Bad Request"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225768/discussion-between-vonc-and-kiran).

Comment: i am using correct project id and project url

Comment: @VonC: is there a way I force creating a tag by API? I am trying to track my version moved to production by tag by I am getting tag exist after creating for first time.

Comment: @Amir I do not see that in [glab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/tree/main/docs/source), or in the [Tags API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html). That does not seem supported. SO you might need to delete first, then recreate.